# Why is the "files" property in package.json dangerous?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, whitelist, blacklist

I noticed that when using airbnb/prop-types there was a load of files that didn't seem to be needed, including all the tests. So I raised [a pull request](https://github.com/airbnb/prop-types/pull/66) to use the "files" property of package.json to only select the required files. But the request was declined. Part of the reason was that:

> Additionally, the “files” property is very dangerous; only .npmignore should be used to prevent publishing of files.

Why is it dangerous? I would have thought whitelisting is better than blacklisting.

Comment: just a guess that a test might run and pass but require files are missed so inclusive is considered by that person as safer. Of course a CI would seem to catch that so seems to me like files is "safer". less chance for a stray file to get accidently included